# Find the value of $\lambda$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Saw this one while JEE prep.

**Question:** Let $f(x)$ is a function continuous for all $x \in R$ except at $x=0$. Such that $f'(x)>0$ for $x \in (0,\infty)$ and $f'(x)<0 $ for all $x \in (-\infty , 0)$.

Let $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=2$,  $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^-}f(x)=3$ and $f(0)=4$

Then what is the value of $\lambda$ for which $$2(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x^3-x^2))=\lambda(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(2x^4-x^5))$$

My attempt: I tried drawing a graph and comparing this to a tampered graph of $y=x^2$ but didn't got much far. Can someone guide me on how to solve it?

Comment: Limit on LHS is simply limit as $x\to 0^-$ because $|x|^3<x^2$ and limit on RHS corresponds to $x\to 0+$. Value of $f$ at $x=0$ is irrelevant for limits. Therefore LHS is $2\times 3$ and RHS is $\lambda 2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a slight abuse of notation we have that:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x^3-x^2) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x^2(x-1))= f(0^+*(-1)) =f(0^-)=3$$

Similarly:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(2x^4-x^5)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x^4(2-x)) = f(0^+*2)=f(0^+) = 2$$

We conclude that:

$$2 *3 =\lambda*2 \Rightarrow \lambda = 3$$

Comment: Is this even allowed!?

Comment: @TheDeadLegend why not?

Comment: Pellenthor I think you already wrote down what I wanted so upvoted for that ^_^

Comment: @TheDeadLegend Yes, because the function is continuous both when $x$ approaches 0 from the left, and when it approaches from the right, and that's exactly what we are doing here (even if it looks otherwise)