# Is the textbook's logic correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

This is in continuation to the conditions given in this question: "[Find the value of $\lambda$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250698/find-the-value-of-lambda)".

I'm now supposed to find: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\left(\left[3f\left(\frac{x^3-\sin ^3x}{x^4}\right)\right]-f\left(\left[\frac{\sin x^3}{x}\right]\right)\right)$$
where $[.]=Greatest\;Integer\;Function$.

Following last question's method, I solved:$$x\rightarrow {0^-}\text{ 
    }f\left(\left[\frac{\sin x^3}{x}\right]\right)=f\left(\left[\frac{\sin x^3}{x^3}x^2\right]\right)\rightarrow f\left(0^+\right).$$

Which means

$$f\left(\left[\frac{\sin x^3}{x}\right]\right)\geq 2\,.$$

But in the answer (in the textbook), they are concluding
$$x\rightarrow {0^-}\text{ 
    }f\left(\left[\frac{\sin x^3}{x}\right]\right)=f\left(\left[\frac{\sin x^3}{x^3}x^2\right]\right)\rightarrow f\left(0^-\right).$$

Am I wrong or are they?

Comment: The last term is a constant equal to $f(0)=4$ and first term tends to $3f(0+)$ so that the overall limit is $6-4=2$.

Comment: There ain't an option out of 4 which says 2. @ParamanandSingh

Comment: Then the question is wrong. Also I don't get why you are trying to use $x\to 0^{-}$ when question asks you to find $x\to 0^{+}$.

Comment: The limit for $x\to 0^{-}$ is clearly $9-4=5$. Let me know if your question is about $x\to 0^{+}$ or $x\to 0^{-}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, note that when $x\to 0^{+}$ then we have $$0<\sin x^{3}<x^{3}<x$$ and hence $$\left[\frac{\sin x^{3}}{x}\right]=0$$ and hence the last term is a constant equal to $f(0)=4$.

Next we can see that $$\frac{x^{3}-\sin^{3}x}{x^{4}}\to 0^{+}$$ as $x\to 0^{+}$ and hence $$f\left(\frac{x^3-\sin^{3}x}{x^{4}}\right)\to f(0+)^{+}=2^{+}$$ and note that the $+$ in $2^+$ is because $f'(x) >0$ for $x>0$.

Thus first term is also a constant equal to $6$ and the final limit is $6-4=2$.